React, SSR, how to display different Themes/Templates according additional request to CMS
Our team uses React with SSR. I received a request to find a way to render one of several templates, all of which look different (e.g., with or without a sidebar, with or without a footer) according to a configuration from the CMS.
However, at the start, the server sends an initial HTML template without knowing which template needs to be rendered. It seems like it can only send one default template. The client renders this default template, fetches the configuration from the CMS, and then renders another template according to the configuration. The whole page rerenders, and this is, of course, a bad approach.
Is there any solution to this problem, maybe some libraries, or I have to change of approach?"
I didn't find any existing examples with a similar approach. Is something like this even possible? Or it is possible only with React CSR?
